# FOSUser + BorisMorel LdapBundle

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, ldap

I'm trying to integrate BorisMorel LdapBundle with FOSUser following this guide: [Using a custom user manager with LDAP authentication](https://github.com/BorisMorel/LdapBundle/blob/master/Resources/Docs/ldap_with_custom_user_manager.md)

My objective is to authenticate by using LDAP and then storing the LDAP data in my fosuser table.

I've got to the point where the data is correctly retrieved from the LDAP and stored in the fosuser table. I don't want it to store the password on the database, because there's no use on it, as I prefer the password being validated using the LDAP on each login.

The problem is when I get to this point:
*C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony2\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\UserAuthenticationProvider.php*

In function:
**public function authenticate(TokenInterface $token)**

It calls the function:
**$this->checkAuthentication($user, $token);**

Which resolves this function:
**checkAuthentication(UserInterface $user, UsernamePasswordToken $token)**

Which is in this file:
*C:\xampp\htdocs\Symfony2\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider.php*

Because it checks the password using this:
    **encoderFactory->getEncoder($user)->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $presentedPassword, $user->getSalt())) {
    throw new BadCredentialsException('The presented password is 
    }**

As the password on the fosuser table is empty, the authentication always fails, even if it already passed the LdapBundle test.

What I'm missing? I'm guessing that the wrong validator is being used, but it's not described in the BorisMorel resources!.

Please help!

Comment: Do you specifically want to use the `BorisMorel\LdapBundle`? There is another bundle (https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle) that works with the `FOSUserBundle` with minimal messing about.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it before but seems it's only compatible with Symfony 2.0.x & I'm using Symfony 2.5 :(

Comment: Version `2.0.*` works with `2.5` (I'm using it at the moment) although it is currently in development so subject to possible changes.

Comment: Thank you, I tried and got the following error:
**Unrecognized options "client" under "fr3d_ldap"**

Could you please be so kind to provide a copy of your config.yml, security.yml ? Thank you!

Comment: The docs for 2.0 haven't been set up but you can see the new configuration parameters in https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/blob/2.0.x/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php although there are no docs. My security.yml just has `fr3d_ldap: ~` in the main firewall.

Comment: Thank you so much Qooq, Fr3dLdapBundle was way easier to configure. Also, the docs are available for 2.0, you just have to change the branch in GitHub:
[https://github.com/Maks3w/FR3DLdapBundle/blob/2.0.x/Resources/doc/index.md](LdapBundle 2.x docs)

Could you please make it an anwser so I can accept it?